# Ajax returning HTTP response 501: method not implemented

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, linux, apache

I am requesting a simple php file that echos a single line; using AJAX, but I am getting a HTTP 501 response from my localhost server on linux. My question is, What could be causing this kind of error?

**JavaScript:**

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    //console.log(request.responseText);
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        console.log(0);
    } else if (request.status == 501) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    }
}
request.open('test.php', 'GET', true);
request.send();
```

*test.php:*

```
<?php echo 'this is a test'; ?>
```

Comment: Possibly your code, which you did not post.

Comment: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E501.html

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code. I recently ran into a similar problem while using `PUT` and `DELETE` on an IIS server as these verbs are not allowed by default. You may be experiencing a similar behavior as I don't think apache (which I presume you're probably using) has support for these verbs enabled automatically either.

Comment: @Musa Sorry, I posted it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as know, you can not detect server the status before `readyState`. If it's `4` (so `DONE`) then can check the server status.

So you need to check first `readyState` before checking `status`.

```
if (req.readyState === 4) {
    // 200 is not enough to detect successful requests
    // cos there are many success status codes
    if (req.status === 200) {
        // every thing ok
    } else {
        // something is wrong with server?
    }
}
```

Have a look HTTP status code here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Maybe this could be useful for you: https://github.com/qeremy/mii/blob/master/mii.ajax.js#L248